# Assert exception thrown or not in a JetPack Compose test

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-jetpack-compose, android-instrumentation

**Problem**

```kotlin
Button(onClick = { throw IllegalArgumentException() }) {
    Text(text = ACTION_THROW_ERROR)
}
```

I have a `Button`. In its `onClick`, I am throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`. How do I test if the exception is thrown or not?

**What I have tried**

1. I've tried `@Test` annotation's `expected` param

```kotlin
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException::class)
fun throwsError_1() {
    composeRule.onNodeWithText(ACTION_THROW_ERROR).performClick()
}
```

2. I've tried normal `try-catch`

```kotlin
try {
    composeRule.onNodeWithText(ACTION_THROW_ERROR).performClick()
    assert(false)
} catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
    assert(true)
}
```

3. I've tried `Assert.assertThrows`

```kotlin
Assert.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException::class.java) {
    composeRule.onNodeWithText(ACTION_THROW_ERROR).performClick()
}
```

None of these worked

See complete test file [here](https://gist.github.com/theapache64/8c5b0330ea4bd8bf72b89527c15206b7)

**Questions**

- What am I missing here?
- Why is the exception not caught in the test?
- How do I test if the exception is thrown or not in the above scenario?

Comment: The problem is you are throwing error inside the `onClick` lambda but unfortunately it is not catched so it always fails inside the lambda throwing the error. I am not sure how to fix this but this is what happening there

Comment: @Jack I don't think that's the issue here. I've [tried throwing](https://gist.github.com/theapache64/414a83f5d161efdb212e730badbab385) the error inside the `setContent` block. It also fails. 

Comment: I said that because I opened up the log it said `IllegalArgumentException` so I though the catch mechanism not working in the lambda also I am using `createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()` to create composeRule because this is what working for me

Comment: @Jack Sorry, I don't get the `createAndroidComposeRule` part. So the same test with `createAndroidComposeRule` working for you?

Comment: No even with that it's not working :(